# What was the Cathars' / Albigensians' political philosophy?

Tags: civil-government, heresy, politics, catharism

What was the Cathars' or Albigensians' political philosophy? Was it the same as the Manicheans'? Who were these movements' prominent political philosopher-theologians?

All these [dualists](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=33236) thought that marriage and the body were evil; so it would seem that they would think the family, the fundamental cell of society, is evil, too, and thus all of civil society evil.

Comment: A few texts survived the crusade http://gnosis.org/library/cathtx.htm It's doubtful they contain a political philosophy judging by their titles. You can read the main/longest one in under an hour http://gnosis.org/library/cathar-two-principles.htm